# Error in generate protocol buffers in grpc node

Tags: node.js, grpc, protoc, grpc-node

I wanna build a microservice with gRPC in Nodejs, but I got an error.

I installed `grpc-tools@1.12.4` and `google-protobuf@3.21.2`, but when I enter this command:

```
grpc_tools_node_protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./generated --grpc_out=./generated --proto_path=./protos ./protos/*.proto
```

I get this error:

```
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grpc-tools\bin\protoc.js:41
    throw error;
    ^

Error: Command failed: \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grpc-tools\bin\protoc.exe --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grpc-tools\bin\grpc_node_plugin.exe --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./generated --grpc_out=./generated --proto_path=./protos ./protos/*.proto

←[90m    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)←[39m
←[90m    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)←[39m
←[90m    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)←[39m
←[90m    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:441:11)←[39m
←[90m    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)←[39m
←[90m    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:674:12)←[39m {
  killed: ←[33mfalse←[39m,
  code: ←[33m3221225781←[39m,
  signal: ←[1mnull←[22m,
  cmd: ←[32m'\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\grpc-tools\\bin\\protoc.exe --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\grpc-tools\\bin\\grpc_node_plugin.exe --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./generated --grpc_out=./generated --proto_path=./protos ./protos/*.proto'←[39m
}
```

it drives me crazy :(

Comment: Apart from grpc-tools and google-protobuf, make sure you have protobufjs installed as well. 
Did you install protobufjs?

Comment: No I just installed grpc-tools and google-protobuf global

Comment: if then try this and let me know.

Comment: protobufjs is an entirely separate tool from grpc-tools and google-protobuf. There is no interaction, and there is never any need to install protobufjs for grpc-tools or google-protobuf to work.

Comment: I installed protobufjs but it still doesn't work @david-teo

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact cause and issue but downgrading `@grpc/grpc-js` to **1.6.6** and `grpc-tools` to **1.11.2** worked for me.